# Get coordinates from google latLng class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable with this value LatLng(23.83838, -22.42322).
`var latLng = coordinates;` returns:
`LatLng(23.83838, -22.42322)`.

How do I get the values by index in dart?

something of this sort `latLng[0]` should return `23.83838` and `latLng[1]` `-22.42322`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
```

```
LatLng data= LatLng(23.83838, -22.42322);
print('${data.latitude} ${data.longitude}');
```

output

[image]

Comment: I tried this earlier. It gives a class type error. Even creating a class manually doesn't solve that. ``TypeError (type 'LatLng' is not a subtype of type 'LatLng' where
  LatLng is from package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart
  LatLng is from package:app/services/state.dart``

Comment: I tried to run the code and it worked, see my updated answer! maybe there is confliction in your imports that is why you are facing the issue.try to remove import from `package:app/services/state.dart `